# Change domain, redirect and don't lose page rank

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I have a well-known domain name and receive something like 5k visitors per day.
But i really want to change my domain and my pages title, a complete renew!

Have some way to do this without losing my page rank and visitors?
For example, now if someone from my country (brazil) search about a tablet my site will appear in first page.

In really, i have 3 sites with one domain.

```
shop.mydomain.com
forum.mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com (wordpress blog)
```

If possible i want to change just the shop domain.
A long time ago i read about a changes like that, 301 redirect or something like this that preserves your page rank and google position.
My new domain is exatcly the keywork that my visitors search, probably with this change i will get the first place in searches.

I do not want lose backlinks

Help please?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [webmasters.se]

Comment: Warning -- even if you keep your URL path structure and hierarchy intact, utilize 301 redirects and do just about everything else any SEO will recommend, you will still suffer at the hands of Google if you rename your domain.

There is no way around this.

Comment: If i redirect just my shop sub domain and dislike the results, i will can erase the 301 redirect from htacess and all will back to normal?

Comment: Changing an established domain to another just to get a keyword in the url isnt worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Matt Cutts explains](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en), a 301 redirect is the best way to redirect users:

> If you need to change the URL of a page as it is shown in search engine results, we recommend that you use a server-side 301 redirect. This is the best way to ensure that users and search engines are directed to the correct page. The 301 status code means that a page has permanently moved to a new location.

[This CSS Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/301-redirects/) explains how to implement a 301 redirect, but essentially:

If you want to use a 301 redirect (which is the quickest, cleanest, and most search engine friendly option) to direct browsers to an entirely new website, place this line in the `.htaccess` of the old site

```
Redirect 301 / http://newsite.com/
```

If you only want to redirect a particular page, place this in the `.htaccess` of the old site

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.yoursite.com/newpage.html
```